# remove duplicates from list of tuples based on highest value

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've got list similar to that but its length will vary and the content too. I need to remove the duplicates of the 1st position in tuple, but I need to keep the highest value from the 2nd position. Order is not important in the end data will be sorted by either 1st or 2nd position depending which will be more needed. For eg. for 2186.11 would be 80 not 49. Please help :)

```
[('2186.11', '49'), ('1251.67', '48'), ('1267.67', '26'), 
 ('1383.77', '824'), ('163.96', '29'), ('170.00', '29'), 
 ('170.72', '51'), ('2186.11', '80'), ('170.00', '22')]
```

def Remove_Duplicates(infile):

```
singles = []
test = []
for elem in infile:
    if type(elem) == tuple:
        test.append(elem[0])
        if not elem[0] in singles:
            singles.append(elem)
        if elem[0] in singles:
            position = singles.index(elem)
            if elem[1] > position[1]:
                position[1] = elem[1]
            else:
                pass
    else:
        if not elem in singles:
            singles.append(elem)

return singles
```

Thats a code I came up with. But i got the answer. Thank you guys.

Comment: Can you show your current code for this? Explain what difficulties/errors you are currently experiencing. Please make sure you edit your question to ensure you put together a proper [mcve].

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> L=[('2186.11', '49'), ('1251.67', '48'), ('1267.67', '26'), ('1383.77', '824'), ('163.96', '29'), ('170.00', '29'), ('170.72', '51'), ('2186.11', '80'), ('170.00', '22')]
>>> list(dict(sorted(L, key=lambda v: int(v[1]))).items())
[('2186.11', '80'), ('170.00', '29'), ('1267.67', '26'), ('1383.77', '824'), ('163.96', '29'), ('1251.67', '48'), ('170.72', '51')]
```

Sort by the numerical value of the second item then convert to a dictionary to remove duplicates and convert back.

Answer (score 1):

assuming I understand what you're looking for:

```
example = [('2186.11', '49'), ('1251.67', '48'), ('1267.67', '26'), ('1383.77', '824'), ('163.96', '29'), ('170.00', '29'), ('170.72', '51'), ('2186.11', '80'), ('170.00', '22')]

example.sort(key=lambda x: int(x[1]))
result = list(dict(example).items())
result
[('1267.67', '26'),
 ('163.96', '29'),
 ('1383.77', '824'),
 ('1251.67', '48'),
 ('170.00', '29'),
 ('170.72', '51'),
 ('2186.11', '80')]
```