# How to filter a set of (int, str) tuples, to return only tuple with min value in first element?

Tags: python, filter, set, tuples, min

Suppose I have a set of tuples representing URLS with "scores":

`{(0.75, 'http://www.foo.com'), (0.33, 'http://www.bar.com'), (0.5, 'http://www.foo.com'), (0.66, 'http://www.bar.com')}`.

What is a  concise way for me to filter out duplicate URLS, returning only the URL with the lowest score? That is, from the example set above, I want to get the following set, where each URL appears only once, with the lowest corresponding score from the original set:

`{(0.5, 'http://www.foo.com'),(0.33, 'http://www.bar.com')}`

I came up with the following solution:

```
from collections import defaultdict

seen = defaultdict(lambda:1)
for score, url in s:
    if score < seen[url]:
        seen[url] = score

filtered = {(v,k) for k,v in seen.items()}
```

... but I feel like there is probably some simpler and more efficient way to do this without using the intermediary dict to keep track of the max element, and then regenerate the set from that. What is the best way to filter a set of tuples by the min/max of the first element?

Comment: I found [a duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43836046/1222951), but it's terrible and I don't feel like editing it into shape. So unless someone else wants to do that, I'll wait for answers to be posted here and then close the older question as dupe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've already implemented the simplest approach I can think of. The only change I'd make would be to the loop—a slightly more concise version is using `min`.

```
seen = defaultdict(lambda: 1)  # `lambda: float('inf')` if scores can be > 1
for score, url in s:
    seen[url] = min(seen[url], score)

{(v,k) for k,v in seen.items()}
# {(0.33, 'http://www.bar.com'), (0.5, 'http://www.foo.com')}
```

---

If you really want a shorter solution, like I said, it isn't the simplest approach, but it is a one liner. Most of the challenge is interchanging the URL and the score so you can use the URL as a key when dropping duplicates. It goes without saying that sorting is a pre-condition here (that's why I don't like this solution as much as the one above).

```
{(v, k) for k, v in dict(sorted(((v, k) for k, v in s), reverse=True)).items()}
# {(0.33, 'http://www.bar.com'), (0.5, 'http://www.foo.com')}
```

This solution becomes so much shorter if `s` looks like this:

```
s2 = {(v,k) for k, v in s}
s2 
# {('http://www.bar.com', 0.33), ('http://www.bar.com', 0.66), ...}
```

You'd only then need to do

```
list(dict(sorted(s2, reverse=True)).items())
# [('http://www.foo.com', 0.5), ('http://www.bar.com', 0.33)]
```

Comment: your last piece of code relies on the implementation detail of how a `dict` is being initialized from a list of tuples, overwriting last value for a key each time. This probably won't stand the test of time, and has implicit assumptions.

Comment: @guyarad It isn't an implementation detail. Dictionaries always use the last value. This is fine as long as you're passing an ordered collection (such as a list).

Comment: @guyarad That's documented behavior, not an implementation detail: *"If a key occurs more than once, the last value for that key becomes the corresponding value in the new dictionary."* (From [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict).)

Comment: Ah nice - I like the use of `min()` instead of the conditional. It took me a minute to understand your last solution, and I am going to go with the 1st, both for readability and because I want to avoid the sorting (the sets of URLS can be rather large). But it is an interesting  technique - I had no idea that dict initialization could be used in this way to filter out duplicate keys. Thanks very much. +1

Answer (score 1):

Without any tricks or additional code for reuse you are pretty close. I came up with something similar that's a little cleaner in my opinion:

```
seen = set()
filtered = []
for score, url in sorted(urls):
    if url in seen:
        continue
    filtered.append((score, url))
    seen.add(url)
```

You can also utilize other libraries, such as [boltons](https://boltons.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). You can use the [unique](https://boltons.readthedocs.io/en/latest/iterutils.html?highlight=unique#boltons.iterutils.unique) method like so:

```
import operator
from boltons.iterutils import unique
filtered = unique(sorted(urls), key=operator.itemgetter(1))
```

*Update*: if the tuples have all relevant scoring as the first elements, this solution would work for arbitrary length of tuples (assuming you change the key function)

Answer (score 1):

Another solution:

```
seen = {}
for score, url in s:
    if seen.setdefault(url, score) > score:
        seen[url] = score
filtered = {(v,k) for k,v in seen.items()}
print(filtered)
```

Answer (score 1):

A very simple approach:

```
L=sorted(s,key=lambda t: (t[1],t[0]))
[L[0]] + [L[i] for i in range(1,len(L)) if L[i][1]!=L[i-1][1]]
```